# What is the best and quickest way to set up a google map in android?

Tags: android, google-maps, android-asynctask

I'm creating an app that will basically allow users to save their location as a crag (rock climbing). I'm saving the info in a database behind a content provider. But the problem is in setting up the Google map I'm using to allow users to set their location. At the moment I'm setting in up when the location provider is connected, using the onConnected() method, this seems to slow the starting of the activity. I tried to speed it up by doing the map stuff in an ASyncTask but this crashes because maps doesn't seem to want to run in another thread.

Here's my code:

```
package com.fooforever.climbtrack;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.location.Location;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.NavUtils;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.CheckBox;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.google.android.gms.common.ConnectionResult;
import com.google.android.gms.common.GooglePlayServicesClient;
import com.google.android.gms.location.LocationClient;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.CameraUpdateFactory;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng;

public class AddCragActivity extends Activity implements
    GooglePlayServicesClient.ConnectionCallbacks,
    GooglePlayServicesClient.OnConnectionFailedListener{
    private GoogleMap map;
    private LocationClient locationClient;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_addcrag);
        locationClient = new LocationClient(this, this, this);
        locationClient.connect();
        setUpMapIfNeeded();
    }

    public void onClickSave(View v) {
        CheckBox tradCb = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.tradCb);
        CheckBox boulderCb = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.boulderCb);
        CheckBox sportCb = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.sportCb);
        EditText cragName = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.cragNameEt);
        String name = cragName.getText().toString();
        String type = "";
        if(tradCb.isChecked()) {
            if(type.isEmpty())
                type = "Trad";
            else
                type = type.concat(" Trad");
        }
        if(boulderCb.isChecked()) {
            if(type.isEmpty())
                type = "Bouldering";
            else
                type = type.concat(" Bouldering");
        }
        if(sportCb.isChecked()) {
            if(type.isEmpty())
                type = "Sport";
            else
                type = type.concat(" Sport");
        }

        Log.d("ClimbTrack", "type = " + type);
        // check for empty strings
        boolean nisE = name.isEmpty();
        boolean tisE = type.isEmpty();

        if(!nisE && !tisE) {
            // put the info into the database
            ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
            values.put(ClimbProvider.NAME, name);
            values.put(ClimbProvider.TYPE, type);
            Uri uri = getContentResolver().insert(ClimbProvider.CONTENT_URI_CRAGS, values);
            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Saved successfully" , 
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            // go back an activity
            NavUtils.navigateUpFromSameTask(this);
        } else if(nisE && !tisE)
            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "No crag name!" , 
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        else if(!nisE && tisE)
            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "No crag type!" , 
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        else 
            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "No crag name or type!" , 
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    }


    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    private void setUpMapIfNeeded() {
        // Do a null check to confirm that we have not already instantiated the map.
        if (map == null) {
            map = ((MapFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map))
                                .getMap();
            // Check if we were successful in obtaining the map.
            if (map != null) {
                // The Map is verified. It is now safe to manipulate the map.

            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onConnectionFailed(ConnectionResult arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void onConnected(Bundle arg0) {
        //MapTask mapTask = new MapTask();
        //mapTask.execute();
        map.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_HYBRID);
        map.getUiSettings().setZoomControlsEnabled(false);
        map.getUiSettings().setMyLocationButtonEnabled(true);
        map.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
        Location currentLocation = locationClient.getLastLocation();
        LatLng currentLatLng = new LatLng(currentLocation.getLatitude()
                , currentLocation.getLongitude());
        map.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(currentLatLng));
        map.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.zoomTo(15));

    }

    @Override
    public void onDisconnected() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

//  private class MapTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {
//      @Override
//      protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
//          map.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_HYBRID);
//          map.getUiSettings().setZoomControlsEnabled(false);
//          map.getUiSettings().setMyLocationButtonEnabled(true);
//          map.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
//          Location currentLocation = locationClient.getLastLocation();
//          LatLng currentLatLng = new LatLng(currentLocation.getLatitude()
//                  , currentLocation.getLongitude());
//          map.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(currentLatLng));
//          map.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.zoomTo(15));
//          return null;
//      }}
}
```

The ASyncTask is commented here but that's how I implemented it.
Is there any better way than they way I'm doing it without an ASyncTask or a way to do it with one?

Comment: why not just let the map load and the location API connect separately like most apps do?

Comment: If I don't call this from within onConnected() I get a not connected error because its not done yet. So even if I toggled a variable or something in onConnected() I would still be waiting for that to finish before setting up the map. Or am I missing an obvious way to do this?

Comment: for the location stuff yes you would do it there but that does not mean you have to have everything load there like the map type and stuff. if it cannot connect just display a toast saying cannot connect to GPS or whatever. I also see that you are using `map.setMyLocationEnabled(true);` if thats the case why dont you just use the build in `location provider` `map.setOnMyLocationChangeListener(this);`

Comment: I hadn't found doc on that anywhere but that works and speeds everything up, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You are right that calls to the map should happen in UI thread, hence cannot be in AsyncTask. But if you have some markers or polylines you need to fetch from the internet or prepare in other ways, this could preferably be done in the background and then added in onPostExecute.

I do not see any reason to wait for the onConnected before manipulating the map, rather do everything you need in setUpMapIfNeeded() except adding current location:

```
   private void setUpMapIfNeeded() {
    // Do a null check to confirm that we have not already instantiated the map.
     if (map == null) {
        map = ((MapFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map))
                            .getMap();
        // Check if we were successful in obtaining the map.
        if (map != null) {
            // The Map is verified. It is now safe to manipulate the map.
            map.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_HYBRID);
            map.getUiSettings().setZoomControlsEnabled(false);
            map.getUiSettings().setMyLocationButtonEnabled(true);
            map.setMyLocationEnabled(true);

        }
     }
   }
```

And then in onConnected() (only if setup was needed, otherwise it will rezoom every time oreientation changes):

```
Location currentLocation = locationClient.getLastLocation();
LatLng currentLatLng = new LatLng(currentLocation.getLatitude()
        , currentLocation.getLongitude());
map.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(currentLatLng));
map.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.zoomTo(15));
```

*If you really want to handle things such as orientation change, then an idea would be to save current time and current location in onDestroy(). This way you can set the saved location directly inside setUpMapIfNeeded(), if you conclude that the fragment already exists and that the retrieved timestamp is less than, say, 5 seconds old.*

Changed the above to italic as that is completely unnecessary since you only need to add the location once. From then on the map will be reused upon orientation changes and you will not want to zoom to current location again.

**Note:** I can see that this still gives some seconds of delay before first-fix. Though honestly I doubt there is any much better alternatives, as the other methods (such as LocationManager) in my experience gives very inaccurate first-fixes up until GPS is locked.

**Note2:** This is not clear from your code. But if the activity is not your main acitivty, then simply move LocationClient setup to the your main activity and pass the current location to AddCragActivity when it is called.